# Call PL/SQL Web Toolkit procedures from Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, ora-06512

I need to call some PL/SQL procedures from my Java application. I can do it with JDBC. But the problem is that procedures are using the "[PL/SQL Web Toolkit](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_web.htm)" and its packages (htp, owa _ util, owa _ cookie, ...). When I call them I get some exceptions as this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 323
ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 859
ORA-06512: at "SYS.HTP", line 974
...
```

Is possible to call these procedures using a Java package or any other way?

I can't modify these procedures, but I can't create some.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you calling the procedures via Statement's executeQuery() method?

Comment: Well, not at all. I use CallableStatement's execute() method. This class is an Statement's subinterface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

htf and htp assume that some things are going to be set up in advance. This is done automatically when the call goes through a PL/SQL gateway like mod_plsql. But it can also be done manually.

There's a good explanation on the [Ask Toad wiki](http://asktoad.com/DWiki/doku.php/howto_debug_pl/sql_code_that_uses_the_htp_or_htf_packages_to_build_web_applications)

To successfully use htp & htf, you'll need to define a couple variables and then initialize the cgi environment.

Comment: It seems the perfect solution! I'll work on this now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that you are passing an argument of the wrong datatype or assigning the result to a variable of the wrong datatype.  You need to re-check your code and in particular its assignments.   Alterntively you can post your code here: I'm sure one of the SO Brains will be able to spot the problem.

Incidentally, which method in OWA_UTIL are you calling?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sure the procedure arguments are correct. The problem seems to be that some system objects are not created/initialized.
The call stack is: 
MyMethod --> SYS.PRINT('Hello world!') --> SYS.PRN('Hello World') --> OWA_UTIL.GET_CGI_ENV('GATEWAY_IVERSION')

Answer (score 0):

here's the sample code how you can do it ---

```
              CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("? = call test(?)");
              stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
              stmt.setString(2, "callIndex");
              stmt.execute();
              Integer outputValue = stmt.getInt(1);
```

here test is a stored function which is been called via java "callable statement".Also if you need to pass variables to stored procedure or a function in oracle, you have to OracleTypes to pass the correct variable up over there.